# Is there a possibility to implement push notification on an isolated system (no internet connection)?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to write a Xamarin Forms app which would work within an isolated environment. By that I mean no internet connection and only an internal server which would communicate with the mobile devices using WiFi.

I need to send notifications to user's mobile devices and I need to be sure that they are received no matter whether the devices are locked or the app itself is closed on a device (hence the need for Push Notifications)

Is it possible to use Push Notifications in such a setup?

If so, please kindly provide me with guidance where to search for additional resources (how to implement push on aforementioned internal server).

If not possible, how can I substitute Push Notifications.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "actual" push message from the app to the screen is done on the device after a notification is received via firebase service from the push server. So, in theory, it is possible. But you would not be able to do it via the official firebase push service, you would need to create a local rest API server for example, that the app can poll every x seconds to check if there is a push message. And if there is a push message you send a notification to the phone so it is displayed on the screen.

For this to work when the phone screen is off and/or app is not active, you would need to set up a background service.

below are resources to help you with backgrounding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1YzyreS4-o

Comment: I would like to avoid polling. Would sending a message to the device (i.e. UDP) and listening for it via mentioned background service (and subsequently pushing it to the screen) do the trick?

Comment: yep, agreed, or Mqtt might even be a better protocol to use. Rest api would most likely be easier though so in a first iteration it might be preferable until you get everything around it working.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll go with that. I Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft's SignalR for such a purpose. That way, you can push messages to your clients via a socket connection easily.